# Formatar string para JSON

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 public static string SendSMS(List<string> numbers, string usuario, string message)
        {

            int count = 0;
            string keerpersNumbers = "";
            string urlSMS = "https://minhaurl";
            string authHeader = "Basic bWFshkjhkj=";
            string contentTypeHeader = "application/json";

            if (numbers != null && numbers.Count > 0)
            {  //separar os numero para o json
                foreach (string num in numbers)
                {
                    //keerpersNumbers = num;
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        keerpersNumbers = keerpersNumbers + "," + num;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        keerpersNumbers = num;
                    }
                    count++;
                }

                if (usuario == null && usuario.Equals(""))
                {
                    usuario = "app";
                }

            }

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlSMS);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = contentTypeHeader;
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = contentTypeHeader;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"from\":\"InfoSMS\", \"to\":\"[5531989872881]\",\"text\":\"Test SMS.\"}";
                string contents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Que funciona, mas como veem, é estático. Gostaria de que esta string `json` utilizasse as variáveis do metodo, mas, tento formatar e sempre recebo o erro 400 do servidor.

Como fazer isso? obrigado!

EDIT:

JSON

```
{  
   "from":"WineShop",
   "to":[  
      "5531984882881",
      "5531984882881"
   ],
   "text":"Wine shop grand opening at Monday 8pm. Don't forget glasses."
}
```

Comment: você tem certeza que o array de números devem ser uma inteiros representados em uma string? `"[5531989872881]\"`

Comment: eu envio uma string, como pode ver nos parametros da mensagem. o JSON eu vou adicionar na pergunta

Comment: Então o Json apresentado é diferente do que está declarado no código mais acima da pergunta

Comment: é essa a pergunta, como formatar o json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo o formato apresentado na primeira parte da pergunta onde a propriedade `to`
reflete a seguinte estrutura `"to":"[123456,12354]"`... Você pode simplesmente interpolar a sua `string`.

```
string json = $"{{\"from\":\"{usuario}\", \"to\":\"[{string.Join(',', numbers)}]\",\"text\":\"{message}\"}}";
```

**Resultado**

```
{"from":"Teste", "to":"[123456,123456,123456c]","text":"teste"}
```

Agora no segundo modelo apresentado mais adiante, basta você criar uma `POCO` para refletir o a estrutura desejada e assim utilizar o `JsonConvert` para a serialização e deserialização.

```
class JsonSMSRequest
{
    public string from { get; set; }
    public List<string> to { get; set; }
    public string text{ get; set; }
}

//...

var jsonObject = new JsonSMSRequest{ from = usuario, to = numbers, text= message };
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

**Resultado**

```
{"from":"Teste","to":["123456","123456","123456c"],"text":"teste"}
```

Comment: esse realmente era o problema que apresentou a seguir, ele lia uma string inteira e o SMS não chegava. Vou testar e retorno caso funcione, muito obrigado!

Comment: funcionou certinho! muito obrigado. Não posso upar a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Crie um objeto para conter os dados do json:

```
string numTel = "998877776";
string textoMSG = "teste teste";
object objMSG = new { from = "InfoSMS", to = numTel, text = textoMSG };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objMSG);
```

o objeto `objMSG` ainda pode ser uma classe que represente a MSG a ser enviada, com os parametros from,to e text.

Comment: Pode fazer um ```foreach``` com a lista de números já existente ```numbers``` e em cada laço do ```for``` realiza o preenchimento das classes e parâmetros para o envio.

Comment: já tenho este laço e ele realiza, devo inserir na string de numeros os colchetes? para indicar ao json que é uma lista?

Comment: somente os numero são listas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá
eu tambem estou a trabalhar com json criei um ficheiro .json e adicionei ao meu script desta forma:

```js
$.getJSON("dados.json", function(json) { 

 //aqui programas o que queres com o ficheiro json
 
 });
```

O que está entre "" é o nome do meu ficheiro

e podes organizar o teu ficheiro desta forma:

```js
[
  {  
   "from":"WineShop",
   "to":5531984882881,
        5531984882881
   "text":"Wine shop grand opening at Monday 8pm. Don't forget glasses."
  }
]
```

Observação: Em números não metas "".